# String search and split

Tags: php, html

So I have the following string

```
/home/design/Baie/Design-Interior-Baie-019.jpg
```

Now is there a way to search for the word `Baie` and get back a string like this:

```
/home/design/Baie/
```

I'm trying to build a breadcrumb

Comment: Will you always want the first instance of the word you search for? e.g. "Baie" is in your string twice in this example. Also, do you only want to match entire words between delimiters (`/word/`), or just any instance of the word?

Comment: YOu can use ```explode( 'Baie','/home/design/Baie/Design-Interior-Baie-019.jpg')[0]``` for your example, I think my solution will work but you need to be more specific to get a good answer .

Comment: Are you looking for a solution in JavaScript or in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var abcd = "/home/design/Baie/Design-Interior-Baie-019.jpg"
//Search
var n = abcd.search("Baie");
//split provide sub string
var xyz = abcd.split('Design');

consol.log(xyz[0])
```

Or PHP

```
$abcd = "/home/design/Baie/Design-Interior-Baie-019.jpg";
$xyz = explode('Design', $abcd);
print_r($xyz)
```

Comment: sorry I had the js tag in, I need this for php

Comment: I answered using php also you can try that

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dirname` to return what you are looking for

```php
echo dirname('/home/design/Baie/Design-Interior-Baie-019.jpg');
```

Comment: will `dirname` preserve the last `/` ?

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, assuming your breadcrumb ends at the first occurrence of "Baie" in your path:

```
$search = "Baie" ;
$path = "/home/design/Baie/Design-Interior-Baie-019.jpg" ;
$breadcrumb = substr($path, 0, stripos($path, $search . "/")+strlen($search)+1 );
print $breadcrumb ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '/home/design/Baie/Design-Interior-Baie-019.jpg';
$search = 'Baie/';
$pos = strpos($str, $search);
$result = '';
if ($pos !== false) {
    $result = substr($str, 0, $pos + strlen($search));
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: You should explain your code. Just plopping some code into an answer without an explanation of any kind is not helpful to the OP or any future viewers of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [dirname()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_dirname.asp) function

```
dirname('/home/design/Baie/Design-Interior-Baie-019.jpg');
```

Or you can also try

```
<?php

$word = 'Baie'; 

$string = "/home/design/Baie/Design-Interior-Baie-019.jpg";

$bread =  explode( "$word", $string);

echo $bread[0]."/$word/";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript with indexOf and slice :

```
var str = "/home/design/Baie/Design-Interior-Baie-019.jpg";
var search = "Baie"
if (str.indexOf(search) != -1 )
   var result = str.slice(0,str.indexOf(search)+search.length+1);
console.log(result); // /home/design/Baie/
```

Answer (score 0):

What about a regex ?

```
<?php
$array=[];
$path="/home/design/Baie/Design-Interior-Baie-019.jpg"
$pattern = "#^(.*/Baie)/.*$#";
preg_match($pattern,$path, $matchx);
echo $match[1];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first occurrence use:

```
$path = "/home/design/Baie/Design-Interior-Baie-019.jpg";
$find = "Baie";

$pos = strpos($path,$find);
```

Then to get the first half you can use substr():

```
$newstr = substr($path, 0, $pos + strlen($find));

echo $newstr;
```

This should result in:

```
/home/design/Baie
```

see also:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php